# Java Lambda on an Object Collection

Tags: java, android, lambda

I am playing around with the new Lambdas in Java 8 in Android Studio and attempting to utilize the below line:

```
public Contact findContactByCode(String ContactCode) {
    return this.list.stream().filter(o -> o.getType().getCode() == ContactCode).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The list object is a generic ArrayList, for which the generic type has been assigned to the Contact Model.  Everything is good until I get to the collection function and that is where I am getting the below error:

*"no instance of variable T exists so that List< T > conforms to Contact, inference variable R has incompatible bounds:  Equality constraints: List< T >, Upper bounds: Object, Contact"*

Everything that I am seeing looks correct, but I am not quite sure what is going wrong.

Comment: What are you assigning the return value of `collect()` to?

Comment: Please post few more lines of your code including instantiation of the array list.

Comment: Indra Basak, I have include the entire function.  Which is not much.

Comment: `Contact` is not a `List`. Change the method to return `List<Contact>`

Answer (score 1):

You are attempting to return a List, but the method declaration calls for returning a Contact. Change one of those and you should be fine